# How to use localStorage event listener on multiple instances of the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, setinterval

Assume we have a simple HTML page, homepage.html.

It references two Javascript pages: one.js and two.js that use jQuery.

one.js includes a $(document).ready(function () { statement. 
two.js contains functions used across multiple pages but no ready function.

A user opens two instances of homepage.html in their browser (Safari, to be specific).

two.js has the following code at the top:

```
$(window).bind('storage', function (e) {
  console.log('Only fires for pages OTHER than the current one...<---- IMPORTANT!!!', e);
  if (e.key === "test"){
    console.log('Changing test...', localStorage.test);
  } 
});
```

Here's the issue: **when localStorage.test is updated in EITHER of the two instances BOTH instances show "Changing test..." in the console.**

I was operating on the understanding that a localStorage listener only fired on pages OTHER than current one.

But perhaps because these are the same file NAMES this statement about localStorage event listeners is not true?

I would hope that only the instance of homepage.html that is NOT active would show the message.

What am I missing?

Comment: Only hving one timer is also problematic if user closes the tab where it is running and leaves open another

Comment: Can you add the code that updates the localStorage? Since the event should only fire on the pages that didn't cause the change, we should look into when the `setItem('startTimer')`, `removeItem('startTimer')`, and `clear()` methods are being called.

Comment: Spiny, thanks for taking a look. I will post...but it seems like because the js file is the same, because we are talking duplicates of the same page, the event fires on the page that updates the localstorage variable as well as the other instances. Because it has the same file name maybe?